# Let customers pay products with multiple likes on a share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, e-commerce

Is it possible to integrate Facebook in a webshop so customers can pay by letting their friends like a certain page?
For example someone wants buy product "A" valued 5 EUR or 100 likes. The customer shares a unique link on their Facebook profile, when this share gets 100 likes the order is completed and the product gets delivered.

Answer (score 2):

According to the platform policy, it is not allowed - you can´t reward users in any way for liking. Or for making their friends like something. Users can´t benefit from sharing something on their wall.

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ (4.5)

Even if it would be allowed, you would need access to the user feed with the `user_posts` permission. Facebook will never approve it in the Login Review for something that is not allowed.